# Android Studio service stops after phone locked

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My service stops after 15-20 minutes but when i unlock the phone it starts again.
How can i make it work even when phone sleeps.

I added this to my service oncreate method

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    wl.acquire();
```

And I also added this to oncreate

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),3333,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Perhaps the device has gone into Doze mode. In general, you cannot keep your code running continuously on Android 6.0+ devices.

Comment: Whatsapp can do it

Comment: Most likely, Whatsapp is responding to FCM messages, not running continuously.

Comment: So, there is no way to do it?

Comment: You are welcome to ask the user to add your app to the battery optimization whitelist in Settings, so that you are not affected by Doze mode. The user may not want to do this.